# opencv java - Is it possible to remove background from static image

Tags: java, opencv, image-editing

I am trying to remove background from an image. These are the images of x-ray objects. Since these are static still images, is it possible to remove the background from static image?
Is yes then what is the best way?

Your answer is highly appreciated as I have spent days trying to figure it out and haven't found any possible solution

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: You can try that by thresholding your input image. It would be better if you share your image